# Android: issue of Image Resolution while draw bitmap on canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, android-canvas

On drawing on canvas if i use this code to draw the bitmap then it get stratched.

Code1:

```
photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), true); // original
```

But if i use below code to draw the bitmap then the Bitmap not getting stratched but i m only getting the some portion of top left corner of the Image.

Code2:

```
photoBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap);
```

Now, Above both code is for creating/getting the bitmap. and to draw the Bitmap on canvas i use below code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap (photoBitmap,0,  0, null);// Original Without ImageView
```

Now, What should i do to saw full image and it should not get stratch.

Thanks.

Comment: if your tempBitmap is an original bitmap then is should not stretch on canvas.Please make sure bitmpap scale from original image.

Comment: @Hiren Dabhi: if i use second code then i not stratch but i am getting the image from the camera as well from gallery. So the original image height-width is greater then the device height-width thats why i got only some portion of the image. So what should i have to do ??? i want Whole image but it should not be get stratch.

Comment: I think the word "stratch" is really "stretch",right? So you want to make the bitmap adjust its size to adapt to the screen,with the same height-width ratio, no stretch?

Comment: yes i want as like that and Sorry for the spealing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking to do is to stretch the bitmap in both directions equally so that it fits on the display. Try this:

```
        float xscale = (float)display.getWidth() / (float)tempBitmap.getWidth();
        float yscale = (float)display.getHeight() / (float)tempBitmap.getHeight();
        if (xscale > yscale) // make sure both dimensions fit (use the smaller scale)
           xscale = yscale;
        float newx = (float)tempBitmap.getWidth() * xscale;
        float newy = (float)tempBitmap.getHeight() * xscale; // use the same scale for both dimensions
        // if you want it centered on the display (black borders)
        float borderx = ((float)display.getWidth() - newx) / 2.0;
        float bordery = ((float)display.getHeight() - newy) / 2.0;
        photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, newx, newy, true);

        // your drawing code will now look like this
        canvas.drawBitmap (photoBitmap, borderx,  bordery, null);
```